# text inside tikz node which can skip to an other

Tags: macros, conditionals

I would like to put text in a  mini page with fixed length inside a tikz node using `\sbox` , if the text skip a specified length (10cm) it will be saved in an other `\sbox` and used inside  a tikz node in next page , my MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox{\textone}
\newsavebox{\texttwo}


\newenvironment{leftside}{%
  \begin{lrbox}{\textone}%
  \begin{minipage}[10cm]{8cm}%
  }{%
  \end{minipage}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  % export box register setting outside the scope of the environment
  \global\setbox\textone=\copy\textone
}

\begin{document}

\begin{leftside}
\lipsum
\end{leftside}

\tikz \node[fill=yellow!80!black]
{\usebox{\textone}};

\newpage

\tikz \node[fill=yellow!80!black]
{\usebox{\texttwo}}; %\texttwo save the rest of the text Which goes beyond the length of minipage      

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like `mdframed` provides what you want …

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newmdenv[%
    backgroundcolor=yellow!80!black,
    hidealllines=true
]{leftside}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{leftside}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{leftside}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

The package has lots of options to add frames and backgrounds and you can even access the nodes which are used internally for more dance stuff. See the manual and the examples. Furthermore it is explained how the frames are split across pages (see sec. “A.1. How does mdframed work?”).

Comment: i Defined the length of the mini page to 10cm if the text Exceed this length The remaining part will be saved in \sbox and shown in the next page inside a tikz node

Comment: how to do this with tikz not with mdframed ?

Comment: Sorry I don’t know how this could work in plain TikZ, but did’t you look at the manual of `mdframed` I guess it could help to see how Marco implement this feature ;-)

Comment: Okay. I don’t delete my answer since it may help other coming to this question later …

Comment: @seloumi Why exactly must you do it with `tikz`? You need to explain the context if it is sufficiently specialised to require you use a specific package. If `mdframed` does the job, what's the problem?

Comment: I have a relatively complex code (for me) build on tikz with tests if then else i prefer Better to continue using tikz Rather than the use of other packages .